# EaselJS getObjectUnderPoint and zoom CSS issue

Tags: javascript, css, easeljs, createjs

I have a stage and a container on a single Canvas.

Inside the the stage I add a `Container` which contains two rectangle shapes. I bind a function to the `stagemousedown` event of the stage which returns the shape under the coordinates where the event took place through `getObjectUnderPoint` function.

HTML:

```
<body onload="init();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200">
   </canvas>
   <button onclick="zoom()">zoom it</button>
</body>
```

Function which initialize the stage, container and the two rectangles:

```
function init() {

    stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    container = new createjs.Container();
    var rect1 = new createjs.Shape();
    rect1.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    container.addChild(rect1);
    var rect2 = new createjs.Shape();
    rect2.graphics.beginFill("#00ff00").drawRect(120, 10, 100, 100);
    container.addChild(rect2);
    stage.on('stagemousedown', onClick);
    stage.addChild( container );    
    stage.update();
}
```

The function that returns the item under the `stagemousedown` event:

```
function onClick(e) {
    alert(stage.getObjectUnderPoint(e.stageX, e.stageY));
}
```

This works smoothly until I put `zoom: 2` CSS to body through the `zoom function`. Once I click on the edge of the rectangle, I am not getting the object.

```
function zoom(){
    document.body.style.zoom = 2;
    container.scaleX = container.scaleY = 2;

}
```

I [read](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/278), that EaselJS doesn't work with zoomed canvases. So I put this:

```
container.scaleX = container.scaleY = 2;
```

Which works partially, because there are part of the area which is still not clickable:

[image]

Everything outside the black rectangle area is not triggering the `stagemousedown` event.

How can I be able to make this work?

**NOTE**: I need to use the [stage.on](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_on) method and not [container.addEventListener](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_addEventListener)

http://jsfiddle.net/vqq8dxw7/1/

**EDIT**: Thanks, but the zoom is something I need, because the purpose of the whole thing is to have the whole application zoomed for responsive purposes (without zooming every single html element).

So, I zoom the body, and everything is zoomed like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vqq8dxw7/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle, you aren't updating the stage after you change the scaleX and scaleY of the container so the canvas is never redrawn with the new scale. You ARE, however, still changing the css zoom. You need only change the scale of the container and update the stage.

[I've updated your fiddle to achieve the desired result](http://jsfiddle.net/vqq8dxw7/3/).

```js
function zoom(){
    //document.body.style.zoom = 2;
    container.scaleX = container.scaleY = 2;
    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That was the solution to my actual problem (the one after the edit). EaslJS doesn't consider the `zoom CSS` and the coordinates are created [globally](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/88-resize-and-scale-canvas) and because the zoom is translating the divs.

So I switched to `transform: scale(2);` and using:

```
body.style.top = -body.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
body.style.left = -body.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
```

In order to fix the position of the scaled object.

The reason I didn't think of it before is because I tried it, but I was having this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666688/webkit-transform-scale-making-items-disappear): some items were disappearing after `transform: scale(2)`  was applied.

Then I solved the latter with the workaround suggested in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23223544/4209604) stackoverflow's question, which was:

```
 translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqq8dxw7/6/

**EDIT**: updated the answer because I found that it's not necessary to manually move the body, but you can do it with a "transform origin":

```
document.body.style.transformOrigin = "top left";
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqq8dxw7/11/)